# Tailwind CSS not building

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm currently practicing some tailwindcss frontend design. I've installed it using npm, and I didn't get any errors. I made the build script for tailwindcss. When I run the appropriate command to build the tailwindcss, it doesn't output it to the `style.css` file I set as the output file. I also don't get any errors. This is my code for the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "design",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss build src/style.css -o dist/style.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^1.3.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing `npx` in your command, try this instead:

`npx tailwindcss build src/style.css -o dist/style.css`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#4-process-your-css-with-tailwind

Comment: i tried it, it still didn't work.
wait, will the build work if i run it before creating the ```tailwind.config.js``` file?

Comment: Hmm I think it should work, config file should be optional. But try anyways: `npx tailwindcss init`

Comment: i tried it and it still doesn't work, im not sure why. i tried using it with reactjs as well, but it too didnt work.
Edit: i made a typing error in my ```postcss.config.js```  file in the ReactJs app, it works now, thank you.

Comment: Ahh perfect! happy coding !

Answer (score -2):

**The correct way to add scripts:-**

```
"build": "npx tailwindcss build src/style.css -o dist/style.css"
```